# Angular date display format

Tags: angularjs

```
<td ng-bind="Order.created_at"></td>
```

Displaying output as 2019-12-08 10:34:06

how to show it as     08-12-2019 10:34:06

Comment: Is it Angular or AngularJS?

Comment: it is angularjs

Comment: Give the proper tag

Comment: proper tag means ?

Answer (score 3):

`<td ng-bind="Order.created_at | date:'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss'"></td>`

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 and above use default date pipe like below one.

```
<p>{{ Order.created_at | date:'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</p>
```